# how to read results from aws s3 headObject using PHP SDK v2?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am able to successfully get results back from a call to headObject like this. But then I can't access what's in $result as result is an object (Guzzle\Service|Resource\Model) and the data I see in it is obviously in  protected variables meaning I have to use an object call to get it. But how do I know what the method call should be?

```php
           $result = $client->headObject([
            'Bucket' => $bucket, // REQUIRED
            'Key' => $key // REQUIRED            
        ]);


        $relevantmetaData = array();
        $relevantmetaData['LastModified'] = $result->data['LastModified'];
```

The link [here](http:////docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Guzzle.Service.Resource.Model.html) doesn't mention a method to get at $data

Answer (score 2):

I guess I  should just have tried get(), it works.

```php
$relevantmetaData['LastModified'] = $result->get('LastModified');
```